# Remove background from image (with alpha blending)

Tags: vb.net, image, background, png, alphablending

I have an issue I cannot wrap my head around. Given the following bitmap image:
[image: http://i57.photobucket.com/albums/g239/broa29/buttons_zps1f99a501.png]

How can I get a PNG of just the buttons without the background and with alpha transparent shadows around the edges so I can reuse that PNG over any type of background and not get any glitches? I can't do it during "generation" as the buttons you see are HTML/CSS so all I can get is a bitmap of it.

At first I only had the green background version and figured I would not be able to work with greens if I only did that so I redid the image so that I have R G and B backgrounds to compare with. I can thus easily identify which pixels should be left alone (they are equal in all 3 sections), which need to be 100% transparent (RGB value == background color) and then I'm left with the borders which have a mix of the color and background.

I graduated over 20 years ago so my math classes are really really far away, I don't have much experience toying with color mixing so I'm a bit lost. I read a lot and tried to find algorithms for this and I can't find anything. I tried making one on my own and I got lots of "close but no cigar" attempts. I'd really like to get a pixel perfect algo to do this if anyone has any ideas.

My best shot involves comparing the R G and B values individually in all 3 images. What I found is that there is always 2 that are equal for each channel, so I use that one. The 3rd value which doesn't match I accumulate the 3 values, get the mean of them and use it as my alpha channel. The result isn't too bad, but it's definitely not right. I tried using the inverted luminosity value as the alpha channel and that didn't work too well either.. Tried lots of other things which were even less conclusive.. If I don't touch the alpha channel, the resulting RGB color looks good, but it's blended with black (the more transparent the color should be, the blacker it gets).

A little hand on this one would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You can find out the 'tint' of the alpha parts by inspecting the Red, Green, and Blue backgrounds -- for a full value of Red, the alpha is in Green and Blue. Unfortunately, trying this out in Photoshop I found the contents of the buttons mess up the color selection. Can you generate these images with fully white and/or fully black buttons, or do they always have some shading?

Comment: The "images" are actually CSS/HTML. I can control the background color and I could also generate the button in while or black if needed, but that said, like I mentioned in my question I already have an algo that tells me exactly what pixels should be left as is (the non-alpha part of the buttons) so I currently just ignore those and leave them 100%, no alpha since they are the same in all 3 images. I do the same for the background (easy enough) and set it to 100% alpha.. All I'm left with is the shadows and borders of the buttons where they are semi-transparent. That's where I have trouble.